# do service/system account used for running daemon (webservers, databases) need to have home

Tags: linux, permissions, user-accounts, daemon

I created a system account on Fedora using following commands

```
useradd -r -s /bin/false sysacct
```

Then created a directory and gave permissions to sysacct

```
mkdir /var/sysacct
chown sysacct:sysacct /var/sysacct
```

Now when I try to execute command as sysacct

```
su - sysacct -c 'mkdir /var/sysacct/test'
I get error
```

cannot change directory to  /home/sysacct: No such file or directory

```
Why do I need to specify a home directory for this account?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do service/system account used for running daemon (webservers, databases) need to have home

Generally speaking the account isn't required to have a home directory, but various specific daemons *may* require their $HOME to point to a directory that exists, or may run other tools that require $HOME to exist.

(For example, if a daemon needs to run `gpg` to encrypt data, gpg will require a home directory for storing ~/.gnupg in, even if the daemon itself does not.)

> Why do I need to specify a home directory for this account?

Because you're *asking* `su` to imitate a "real login" procedure which includes changing the working directory to the specified user's home directory. This is documented as part of the effect of `-` or `-l` option.

If you do not want `su` to do this, then do not specify the `-` or `-l` option.

Comment: got it. without the -l option, the su command doesn't ask for home directory. Thank you